# How to set the value of DefaultAzureCredential when using azure/identity in node.js?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-ad-msal

I am using azure/identity package in node.js. I am using `DefaultAzureCredential()` to run it as a specific account of mine. But the problem is when I authenticate against azure keyvault on my local machine, it complains I don't have permissions. When I check the value of the auth token it was using, it wasn't the account I wanted to use, it was using my computer account.

We need to keep it using the `DefaultAzureCredential()` because this works for us when running on prod on Azure. When I try to console log the value of this, I get

```
DefaultAzureCredential {
  UnavailableMessage: 'DefaultAzureCredential => failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials',
  _sources: [
    EnvironmentCredential { _credential: undefined },
    ManagedIdentityCredential {
      isEndpointUnavailable: null,
      identityClient: [IdentityClient]
    },
    AzureCliCredential {},
    VisualStudioCodeCredential {
      cloudName: 'AzureCloud',
      identityClient: [IdentityClient],
      tenantId: 'common'
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried on the same console, `az logout` and then `az login` and logged in on the opened browser the account I wanted. I then tried `az ad signed-in-user show` and it shows the correct account.

This used to work before, but suddenly it stop working without any code changes. Anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Try by signing out from VS Code (and all other places like Azure PowerShell, Visual Studio etc.) and then sign in using just CLI.

Comment: I tried it, but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a cache problem.

Try `az logout --username <username>` with the unwanted account.

The most extreme solution is to delete the `.azure` folder to clear the cache...

Comment: Where is the azure folder?

Comment: In the user folder `C:\Users\<username>`.